# Как объявить один класс в нескольких файлах в C#

Tags: c#

Как объявить один класс в нескольких файлах в C#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# поддерживает частичные классы. Для того чтобы объявить частичный класс, необходимо добавить модификатор partial в объявление класса. Во втором классе это выглядит идентично. Например.

FirstPart.cs

```
partial class SomeClass
{
    // Определение класса 1
}
```

SecondPart.cs

```
partial class SomeClass
{
    // Определение класса 2
}
```