# Разбить код по файлам

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю программу, код пишу в Form1.cs, и кода очень много, приходиться прокручивать страницу то вниз то вверх. Можно ли как то разбить код, на несколько файлов? К примеру Form1.cs Form1_code1.cs Form1_code2.cs
Но чтоб код друг друга видел без всяких пробросов контекста. Подскажите шаблон как это реализовать или ссылку почитать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, можно. Специально для этого используется ключевое слово `partial`

[Разделяемые классы и методы (Руководство по программированию в C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)

Answer (score 5):

Обьявляе в разных файлах один и тот же класс и рядом со слово. class пишете partial. 
C# поддерживает частичные классы. Для того чтобы объявить частичный класс, необходимо добавить модификатор partial в объявление класса. Во втором классе это выглядит идентично. Например.

FirstPart.cs

```
partial class SomeClass
{
    // Определение класса 1
}
```

SecondPart.cs

```
partial class SomeClass
{
    // Определение класса 2
}
```

Данный вопрос уже есть на форуме. Ответ от туда же
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/Как-объявить-один-класс-в-нескольких-файлах-в-c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-c)